# How front-end and back-end are supposed to communicate about links of notifications (routes)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, notifications, deep-linking

I'm trying to implement a react application in which it receives real-time notifications. Some of these notifications must include links, which are routes of application. When the user clicks on a notification, she should be redirected to the specific route.

My question here is how should the backend be aware of these routes? how should they communicate?

The only solution I could think of is to categorize these notifications and routes and, based on their categories, redirect users to the Corresponding routes.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand without knowing more. but your solution for routes if you have a lot of different paths `react-router` seems the way to go. As far as "real-time" notifications I would look into `socket.io` and have your server listen for event changes and what to do with them ect.